# Setting a SQL function parameter default to all

Tags: sql, function, select, parameters, default

Ok so I have a large query that has 4 parameters in it..

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Doorsdoorsdoors]
(
@start datetime, 
@end datetime, 
@day varchar,
@doornumber int
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (

SELECT bla bla bla....
```

What I want to do is set their default parameters to all (*)

So when I use the select statement I can use default so it returns all results like below:

```
SELECT * FROM Doorsdoorsdoors (default,default,default,default)
```

I would imagine it is something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Doorsdoorsdoors]
(
@start datetime LIKE '%', 
@end datetime LIKE '%', 
@day varchar LIKE '%',
@doornumber int LIKE '%'
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (

SELECT bla bla bla....
```

Or possibly done in the `SELECT * FROM Doorsdoorsdoors (default,default,default,default)` with something like this..

`SELECT * FROM Doorsdoorsdoors ('%','%','%','%')`

Comment: You mean you want to retrieve without filtering on any of the 4 at all?

Comment: Yes so i want the default value in the function to be all(*) so when i create that function and then call it using a select statement i can use defaults to return all the values

Comment: What does your query look like. That is actually important.

Comment: Exactly like the above, i have just eliminated the part after SELECT as it is nearing 100,00 characters

Comment: Yes, but the actual where clausewill be important, as you might want to look at passing `NULL`s as **default**

Comment: Have a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/227a4/3) Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: @astander yeah cant use nulls it seems as i get the divide by zero error encoumntered if i use a mixed select `(NULL,NULL,NULL,'33087')` and get no results if i use `(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Doorsdoorsdoors]
    (
    @start datetime = NULL --default value, 
    @end datetime = NULL --default value, 
    @day varchar =NULL --default value,
    @doornumber int = NULL --default value
    )
    RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (

select * from Doorsdoorsdoors where ((@start is NULL) OR (start=@start))
AND ((@end is NULL) OR (start=@end)) AND....
)
```

Call procedure with all defaults:

```
SELECT * FROM Doorsdoorsdoors (default,default,default,default)
```

Comment: I dont want the function parameters to have values, i want the default values within the parameter to be all (*) then when i use call the procedure with all defaults it returns all the values.

Comment: get error **Must declare the scalar variable "@start".** when i run the select part

Comment: Why you run select part if it's part of the function?

Comment: Ignore above, ok so i put it in the function and i get **Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Doorsdoorsdoors, Line 2135
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.**

Comment: Did you fill WHERE with all of parameters? Or you just copy paste without even reading?

Comment: The where statement was as followed.. **`AND  ((@start is NULL) OR (start=@start))
AND ((@end is NULL) OR (end=@end))
AND ((day is NULL) OR (day=@day))
AND ((@doornumber is NULL) OR (doornumber=@doornumber))`**

Comment: There is no `END` statement in my sample of query. Error is on your side. Find place where you use `END`

Comment: The error refers to the `end` in **`AND ((@end is NULL) OR (start=@end))`** i also changed it too **`AND ((@end is NULL) OR (end=@end))`** and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Doorsdoorsdoors]
      (
      @start datetime = NULL,
      @end datetime = NULL, 
      @day varchar = NULL,
      @doornumber int = NULL
      )
      RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (

      SELECT bla bla bla....

      WHERE ((@start is NULL) OR (default=@start))
      AND ((@end is NULL) OR (default=@end))
      AND ((@day is NULL) OR (default=@day))
      AND ((@doornumber is NULL) OR (default=@doornumber))
```

Then try calling it with

```
      SELECT * FROM Doorsdoorsdoors (default,default,default,default)
```

**or**

```
      SELECT * FROM Doorsdoorsdoors (default,default,default,'123')
```

Comment: i get the error **`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.**` when running this.